# asyncpg Pool.execute vs Connection.execute

Tags: python, python-asyncio, asyncpg

What are the use cases for acquiring a connection from a pool and then calling `execute` on the connection rather than calling `execute` on a pool object directly?

In the docs for the [Pool](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.pool.Pool) class, this example is shown:

```
con = await pool.acquire()
try:
    await con.execute(...)
finally:
    await pool.release(con)
```

A connection is acquired from the pool and used to execute a statement. What is the benefit of doing that over just calling the `execute` method directly on the `Pool` object such as the below?

```
async with asyncpg.create_pool(user=pg_user,
                               password=pg_pass,
                               host=pg_host,
                               port=pg_port,
                               database=pg_db,
                               command_timeout=60) as pool:
    pool.execute(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table};')
```

The docs for [`Pool.execute`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=execute#asyncpg.pool.Pool.execute) even state the following:

> Execute an SQL command (or commands).

> Pool performs this operation using one of its connections. Other than that, it behaves identically to Connection.execute().

Answer (score 4):

> What are the use cases for acquiring a connection from a pool and then calling execute on the connection rather than calling execute on a pool object directly?

When you acquire a connection explicitly, you can start a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html) and execute several queries inside of the transaction:

```py
async def transfer_money(pool, from_id, to_id, amount):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.transaction():
            await conn.execute(
                "UPDATE balance SET money = money + $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
                to_id, amount
            )
            await conn.execute(
                "UPDATE balance SET money = money - $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
                from_id, amount
            )
```

If you did this:

```py
async def transfer_money(pool, from_id, to_id, amount):
    await pool.execute(
        "UPDATE balance SET money = money + $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
        to_id, amount
    )
    await pool.execute(
        "UPDATE balance SET money = money - $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
        from_id, amount
    )
```

it would be a shorthand to:

```py
async def transfer_money(pool, from_id, to_id, amount):
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute(
            "UPDATE balance SET money = money + $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
            to_id, amount
        )
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        await conn.execute(
            "UPDATE balance SET money = money - $2 WHERE user_id = $1",
            from_id, amount
        )
```

If, for example, the program crashed after the first query, one user would get the money but the other would not lose it.
In other words, the function would not be atomic (the "A" in [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID))

This is how `Pool.execute` is implemented ([GitHub link](https://github.com/MagicStack/asyncpg/blob/bd192623d05668b5919d55d3b9a62629594e2fb7/asyncpg/pool.py)):

```py
    async def execute(self, query: str, *args, timeout: float=None) -> str:
        async with self.acquire() as con:
            return await con.execute(query, *args, timeout=timeout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. If I understand correctly `Pool.execute` opens and closes a transaction immediately. Whereas executing on a connection object (`Connection.execute`) allows for a little more freedom with deciding what's committed (or rolled back) on a single connection. What if `Connection.execute` wasn't called within a context manager? Then are the two methods (`Connection.execute` and `Pool.execute`) essentially the same?

Comment: Furthermore, in the asyncpg [transactions docs](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#transactions) it states "When not in an explicit transaction block, any changes to the database will be applied immediately. This is also known as auto-commit." So in your second example, wouldn't each call of `conn.execute` be executed immediately in their own transaction even though they're both within the same connection context manager?

Comment: @Ryan, you're right, I completely misinformed you. Acquiring a connection on its own doesn't start a transaction, you need to explicitly call `conn.transaction()`. I've updated the answer